# How can I get consecutive dates in one row using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get starttime minimum and endtime maximum on consecutive dates(must be the same month) , but all dates have to be consecutive.

I want to combine them in one row. How can I get the following table?(Table 2)

| IP Address | Starttime | Endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 15/12/2022 | 15/12/2022 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | **26/12/2022** | 26/12/2022 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 27/12/2022 | 27/12/2022 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 28/12/2022 | **28/12/2022** |
| 192.168. 0.1 | **11/01/2023** | 11/01/2023 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 12/01/2023 | 12/01/2023 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 13/01/2023 | 13/01/2023 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 14/01/2023 | 14/01/2023 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 15/01/2023 | **15/01/2023** |

This is actually what I want:

| IP Address | Starttime | Endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 15/12/2022 | 15/12/2022 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 26/12/2022 | 28/12/2022 |
| 192.168. 0.1 | 11/01/2023 | 15/01/2023 |

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG(endtime)` or `LEAD(starttime) OVER (PARTITION BY ip_address ORDER BY starttime)` on a first pass so that each row can see the date from its neighboring row ( you can go in either direction). Then use a CASE or DECODE to test whether the dates are contiguous or not. If they are not, then emit the date, else emit NULL.  Then in a parent block, you can use LAST_VALUE() with IGNORE NULLS option and ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING TO CURRENT ROW to get the most recent of those conditionally computed dates. That can then be used in a GROUP BY in yet a third parent query block to finalize your results.

Comment: Sir, thank you for answering that challenge question(for me). I've done what you say and I got the right result for some samples. 
Some samples has different dates like
 starttime-> 13/12/2022, endtime->14/12/2022 .
Starttime and endtime are not always equal. Do you any suggestion for that because i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Or the classical MATCH_RECOGNIZE for the merging of intervals:

```
select * from data 
match_recognize(
    partition by ipaddress
    order by starttime, endtime
    measures first(starttime) as starttime, max(endtime) as endtime
    pattern( merged* strt )
    define
        merged as endtime = next(starttime) - 1 
);
```